# Formik calculated field for dynamic fields

Tags: reactjs, formik, calculated-field

I have implemented formik calculated field for static fields and it is working fine. Now I am trying to implement caluclated field for dynamic fields(objects inside an array)

The below code is working fine for fixed fields.

```
const {
            values: { field1, field2 },
            touched,
            setFieldValue,
        } = useFormikContext();
        const [field, meta] = useField(props);

        useEffect(() => {
            var totalAmount = 0;
            totalAmount += field1!== undefined && (!isNaN(parseFloat(field1))) ? parseFloat(field1) : 0;
totalAmount += field2 !== undefined && (!isNaN(parseFloat(field2 ))) ? parseFloat(field2 ) : 0;

            setFieldValue(props.name, totalAmount);

        }, [field1 , field2 , touched.field1, touched.field2 , setFieldValue, props.name]);
        return (
            <>
                <input
                    name="f2"
                    value={field.value}
                />
                {!!meta.touched && !!meta.error && <div>{meta.error}</div>}
            </>
        );
```

Now I need to deal with dynamic fields like below ones. I need a calculated formik field for "income" field of each object.

```
`{
"persons": [
{ "personName" : "" , "income" : 0}
{ "personName" : "" , "income" : 0}

]
}`
```

New Person Object can be added/removed from persons array.

I have no clue how to achieve this as I am new to React. I googled it and there are many examples but all of them are for fixed fields like the one I implemented above for fixed fields. I need to acheive a calculated field for dynamic fields.

My usecase:  Persons array has mulitple person objects and each object has "income" key. Need to calculate the total income of all persons.

I tried the below.

1st strategy:

```
      values: { persons: {income}},
            touched,
            setFieldValue,
        } = useFormikContext();
        const [field, meta] = useField(props);
```

2nd strategy:

```
values: { persons[0]: {income}},
            touched,
            setFieldValue,
        } = useFormikContext();
        const [field, meta] = useField(props);
```

Comment: Hey! Did you manage to figure out this?